# Using a combo box to store items in an array from a text file and then using that array and its components in another form

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently designing an application within visual basic using vb.net. The first form asks for login information and then prompts the next form to select a customer. The customer information is stored in a text file that gets put in an array. I next have a form for the user to display and edit that information. How can I use the array I already created in the previous form in my display and edit form?

```
Private Sub frmCustomerList_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim sr As StreamReader = File.OpenText("customer.txt")
    Dim strLine As String

    Dim customerInfo() As String

    Do While sr.Peek <> -1
        strLine = sr.ReadLine
        customerInfo = strLine.Split("|")
        cboCustomers.Items.Add(customerInfo(0))
        customerList(count) = strLine
        count = count + 1
    Loop
End Sub



Private Sub cboCustomers_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboCustomers.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim customerInfo() As String
    Dim index As Integer = cboCustomers.SelectedIndex
    Dim selectedCustomer As String = customerList(index)

    customerInfo = selectedCustomer.Split("|")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the next form require it in the constructor:

```
Public Class EditCustomer

  Public Sub New(customerInfo As String())
    InitializeComponent() 'This call is required, do not remove
    'Yay! Now you have your info
  End Sub

End Class
```

You'd call it by doing something like...

```
Dim editForm = New EditCustomerFrom(customerInfo)
editForm.Show()
```

Alternatively, you could have a property on the form you set.

```
Dim editForm = New EditCustomerFrom()
editForm.Customer = customerInfo
editForm.Show()
```

Then inside the `Load` event of that form, you'd write the logic that would display it looking at that property.

*Aside:* You should look at maybe defining an object to hold customer info and do some JSON or XML serialization for reading/writing to the file, IMO. This architecture is kind of *not good* as is....